# Сортировкой вектора объектов по 3 параметрам

Tags: c++, сортировка, c++11, перегрузка-операторов, вектор

Есть вектор с указателями на книги. Надо его отсортировать по дате(по году, потом по месяцу и дню). Еще кстати не знаю, если в векторе указатели, то и в comparator надо ставить * или &?
Питаюсь сделать так

```
  bool comparator( Book& a, Book& b) {
    if (a.GetYear() < b.GetYear()) return true;
    if (a.GetYear() > b.GetYear()) return false;
    if (a.GetMonth() < b.GetMonth()) return true;
    if (a.GetMonth() > b.GetMonth()) return false;
    return a.GetDay() < b.GetDay();
}
sort(books.begin(), books.end(), comparator)
```

Выдает такие ошибки

```
error C3867: "HeroFunctions::comp": нестандартный синтаксис; используйте "&", чтобы создать указатель на член
error C2672: "sort": не найдена соответствующая перегруженная функция
error C2780: void std::sort(const _RanIt,const _RanIt): требует аргументов: 2, имеется: 3
```

Пытался сделать с перегрузкой

```
bool operator<(Book* book1, Book* book2)
    {
        if (book1->GetYear() == book2->GetYear())
        {
            if (book1->GetMonth() == book2->GetMonth())
                return book1->GetDay() < book2->GetDay();
 
            return book1->GetMonth() < book2->GetMonth();
        }
        return book1->GetYear() < book2->GetYear();
    }
    sort(books.begin(), books.end())
```

Выдает это

```
error C2804: бинарный "operator <" имеет слишком много параметров
error C2333: HeroFunctions<T,U>::operator <: ошибка в объявлении функции; пропуск основного текста 
  функции
error C2333: HeroFunctions<std::string,Hero>::operator <: ошибка в объявлении функции; пропуск 
 основного текста функции
```

[Вот тут проект. Думаю будет проще, если запустите и там увидете ошибку и сможете исправить](https://github.com/LavrovSergey/test)

Answer (score 1):

Параметры компаратора это ссылки на сравниваемые элементы. Вы пытаетесь отсортировать вектор указателей, следовательно, компаратор должен принимать ссылки на указатели:

```
bool comparator(const Book* const &aa, const Book* const &bb) {

    const Book& a = *aa;
    const Book& b = *bb;

    if (a.GetYear() < b.GetYear()) return true;
    if (a.GetYear() > b.GetYear()) return false;
    if (a.GetMonth() < b.GetMonth()) return true;
    if (a.GetMonth() > b.GetMonth()) return false;
    return a.GetDay() < b.GetDay();
}
```

Comment: Теперь выдает еще больше ошибок. Не могли б вы запустить мой проект и в нем исправить. Так будет значительно быстрее. А то я буду постояннто задавать какие-то вопросы. А так вам сразу будет понятно работает или нет. А мне просто скажите, что исправить надо

Comment: @СергейЛавров, посмотрел ваш проект. Ваш компаратор является функцией-членом некоторого шаблонного класса. Сделайте компаратор статической функцией: `static bool comparator(const Book* const &aa, const Book* const &bb) {...}`. Это не единственная ошибка в проекте, но данная конкретная проблема с компаратором должна решиться.

Comment: на другом форму мне сказали, что не работает из-за того что в векторе указатели и надо их разименовать, а как это сделать я не понял

Comment: Используйте компаратор как у меня в ответе + ключевое слово `static`: `static bool comparator(...){...}`.

Comment: а в векторе сохранятся отсортированные указатели книг?

Comment: @СергейЛавров, набросал небольшой пример для демонстрации, что всё [работает](https://ideone.com/pqvePR). Да, сохранятся.